# Laravel: record not found when querying database within queued event Listener

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have a basic Laravel setup:

- Queue Driver: beanstalkd
- Database: Mysql

I have an event, that fires after registration with `event (new UserRegistered($user_id))`.

```
class UserRegistered
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    private $user_id;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param $user_id
     */
    public function __construct($user_id)
    {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->user_id;
    }
}
```

Event Listener for that Event implements `ShouldQueue`, so it processed by queue.

On `EventListener@handle` method I query database with `$user = User::find($event->getUserId());`

```
class UserRegisteredListener implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  UserRegistered  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(UserRegistered $event)
    {
        $user = User::find($event->getUserId());

        if (is_null($user)) {
            Log::info($event->getUserId());
            Log::error("User not found");

            return;
        }

        // Some work
    }
}
```

**The problem:**

Sometimes (one of 100/1000 i.e) `User::find` returns `null` instead of an record, but I'm sure that such record exists in database!

User ID is ok, I'm logging it to the log file right after this query, and its existing user id.

Any ideas why sometimes record not found in database (when its **exists**)?

**SOLUTION**

I finally found the solution:

I have `DB::beginTransaction` and `DB::commit` calls within registration service. Event was fired **BEFORE** `DB::commit` call, so it was a `race condition` for what will be first: `commit` or event.

Comment: If you dd($event->getUserId()); what does it output?

Comment: it show user id. Its normal user id of existing user.

Comment: which means the method getUserId(), show its code

Comment: Mike, updated quetion, see code.